How to deliver Django+Postgresql projects to clients?
I have been working on a project where my client wants me to load some csv files data into the database and he wants me to use Postgresql. The problem is that sqlite has a physical database stored in django directory which can be delivered along with the project but postgres doesn't work this way. What can I do so that all my relational databases remain intact and I can deliver them to the client's machine?
I saw some search results about dumpdata and load data commands but I was wondering if there is any better way to do this?

You could deliver the entire software stack in containers: https://www.docker.com/blog/how-to-use-the-postgres-docker-official-image/ and https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-postgres-to-kubernetes-cluster

If the source data is CSV, you can import it into PostgreSQL at runtime.
